# When do other areas of town open up?

Tags: story-of-seasons

When I am out wandering, I noticed there are a bunch of places I can't access because they are under construction. Do I just have to wait, and over time they will open, or do I have to do certain things to get access to certain areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Towards the later half of your first spring Veronica will come by and let you know that construction has completed, and these areas are special farms. You will only have access to one when they first open up, and getting rights to the other fields is a different challenge in itself.

Most of the major events/features in the game can be unlocked simply just by getting through a year or 2, with no special effort.

Comment: Challenge in itself? Now I am curious.

Comment: it could be a new question i guess, but Veronica explains it and gives you a book about it when it starts.

Comment: A lot of things only unlock through the trade vendors, and the vendors unlock through shipping, though there's also a minimum date requirement for the first two after the initial one. The last two vendors are notoriously difficult to unlock.